# How can I rename the header on the 'New Account' popup in Salesforce Lightning?

Tags: salesforce, lightning

In Salesforce Lightning, if I go to Accounts and click 'New', the standard lightning popup displays (see image). You'll notice the header states 'New Account: Indirect Transaction Account'. Is there any way to rename that? I can rename the 'Indirect Transaction Account' text by modifying the Record Type Label, but I cannot get rid of the 'New Account:' text.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rename Accounts you can change the label and plural labels for the Standard Object.

If your objective is to get rid of the display label "New Account" then I guess you'll have to overwrite the Account New action with a custom component like a global action, Visualforce or Custom Lightning Component.